# Client username for JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, windows-users

I am building an webapp in JSF-2. I want to know the username of person who is viewing the website.

**Client**

```
<h:outputText value="Welcome #{mailRoomAppView.userID}" style="float: right; float: top" />
```

**Backend Bean**

> public void setUserID(){  userID = System.getProperty("user.name"); }

App is showing Hello mwadmin which is from the system where war is deployed.

I want to get the windows userid of the request 
session

I tried below code but it returns null 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser()

Comment: logged user from session. Nobody knows, what is your code & config

Comment: I'm using JSF2.2. In my backing bean of xhtml, I need to get the username of system of client.

Now I'm using System.getProperty("user.name") but it takes username of server where the app is deployed

Comment: Be more specific with your question and show some code and security configuration for your application

Answer (score 0):

To view the name of the person who is viewing your site, you need the user session.
So, you need some login strategy to identify who is connected.

Once you have a login, you can get the user name with:

```
#{request.userPrincipal}
```

If you want the windows user name, and your app is for a company with LDAP and all PC's are in the same windows domain, you can use the same LDAP for your login.

Comment: Thanks. This is my exact requirement. I don't have any hands on LDAP as well, searching on that.